# Proof of Skolem-Noether for Quaternion Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions

In Corollary 7.1.5 in Voight's [Quaternion Algebras](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Ejvoight/quat-book.pdf), the author gives a direct proof of Skolem-Noether in the case of quaternion algebras. The only challenging step is showing that for a division quaternion algebra $B$ over a field $F$, if $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ have the same minimal polynomial, then they are conjugate. To do this, the author defines the $F$-vector space $$W = \{\beta \in B : \beta \alpha_2 = \alpha_1 \beta\}.$$ He then shows that $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are conjugate in $B \otimes_F F^{\mathrm{sep}}$, and concludes:

> but then by linear algebra $\operatorname{dim}_{F^{\mathrm{sep}}} W \otimes_F F^{\mathrm{sep}} = \operatorname{dim}_F W > 0$, so there exists $\beta \in B \setminus \{0\} = B^\times$ with the desired property.

I see why $\operatorname{dim}_{F^{\mathrm{sep}}} W \otimes_F F^{\mathrm{sep}} = \operatorname{dim}_F W$ by properties of tensor products, but I'm not sure how to use this to conclude that $\operatorname{dim}_F W > 0$ (which is what we are trying to prove, since this implies there is $\beta \in B \setminus \{0\}$ with $\beta \alpha_1 = \alpha_2 \beta$). In particular, if $W$ were $\{0\}$, which is what we are trying to disprove, then wouldn't we have that $\operatorname{dim}_F W = 0$?

Comment: So the author said $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are conjugate via an element $\beta'\in B\otimes_F F^{\rm sep}$? They can't be conjugate via $0$, so that seems to show $W\otimes_FF^{\rm sep}\ne0$, no?

Comment: I suppose it shows that there is $\beta \in B$, $\beta \neq 0$ with $\beta \alpha_1 \beta^{-1} \otimes 1 = \alpha_2 \otimes 1$. Should it be obvious that $b \mapsto b \otimes 1$ is injective here?