How can the following proposition about quaternion algebras be proved?
Problem: Let $ A $ be a quaternion algebra, which is also a non-commutative division ring. Prove that $ x $ and $ y $ are conjugate in $ A $ if and only if $ T(x) = T(y) $ and $ N(x) = N(y) $.
I have completed half of the proof. If $ x $ and $ y $ are conjugate in $ A $, then there exists $ z \in A $ such that $ x = zyz^{-1} $. Since for any $ x, y \in A $, it holds that $ N(xy) = N(x)N(y) $, we have
\begin{align*}
    N(x)=N\left(zyz^{-1}\right)=N(z)N(y)N\left(z^{-1}\right)=N\left(zz^{-1}\right)N(x)=N(x).
\end{align*}
Furthermore, using $ T(x) = x + \overline{x} $, $ \overline{xy} = \overline{y}\ \overline{x} $ and $ N(x) = x\overline{x} $, we deduce
\begin{align*}
    T(x)=T\left(zyz^{-1}\right)&=zyz^{-1}+\overline{zyz^{-1}}=zyz^{-1}+\overline{z}^{-1}\overline{y}\ \overline{z}=zyz^{-1}+N(z)^{-1}z\cdot\overline{y}\cdot z^{-1}N(z)\\
    &=zyz^{-1}+z\overline{y}z^{-1}=z\left(y+\overline{y}\right)z^{-1}=T(y)zz^{-1}=T(y).
\end{align*}
In attempting the other half of the proof, I tried to find a specific $ z $, but this approach doesn't seem to work. I appreciate any hints or assistance offered.

This should help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4705108.

What do you know?  One idea: define a map F[x] to F[y] and show it extends to an endomorphism of A.

Let $K$ be the center of $A$ and let $x,y \in A$ such that $T(x)=T(y)$ and $N(x)=N(y)$. We proceed in two steps.
Step 1: We show that $x$ and $y$ have the same minimal polynomial. Note that $K[x]$ and $K[y]$ are extensions of $K$ of degree at most $2$. If we consider the polynomial $p(Z)=Z^2-T(x)Z+N(x)$. Then we see that $p(x)=x^2-T(x)x+N(x)=x^2-(x+\overline{x})x+x\overline{x}=0$. Since $T(x)=T(y)$ and $N(x)=N(y)$, we also get that $p(y)=0$. If $x \in K$, then we get $p(T)=(T-x)^2$ and hence $p(y)=0$ implies that $x=y$. If $x \notin K$, then $[K(x):K]=2$ and so $p$ must be irreducible for degree reasons. But then $p$ is the minimal polynomial for both $x$ and $y$.
Step 2: Actually, we can generalize this step a little bit. Let $B$ be any centrally simple algebra over $K$. Then I claim that two elements of $B$ with the same minimal polynomial over $K$ are conjugate. This follows from the following version of the Skolem-Noether theorem:

Let $B$ be a central simple algebra over $K$ and let $S$ be a simple algebra over $K$ (not necessarily central), then for any pair of $K$-algebra homomorphisms $f,g:S \to B$, there is a a unit $u \in B^\times$ such that
$$\forall x \in S: f(x)=ug(x)u^{-1}$$

We can apply this in our situation as follows. If two elements $a,b \in B$ share their minimal polynomial $p$ over $K$, then we have two homomomorphisms $f,g:k[Z]/(p) \to B$, where $f$ maps $Z \mapsto a$ and $g$ maps $Z\mapsto b$. Applying Skolem-Noether yiels a unit $u \in B^\times$ such that $f=ugu^{-1}$. Evaluating at $Z$ yields that $a$ and $b$ are conjugate.

I assumed the OP did not know Skolem-Noether because (in my mind) it's immediate from there.  Do you know an argument that does not effectively use Skolem-Noether?
